# Método onCreate() es llamado al cambiar de actividad varias veces

Tags: java, android

He debido de malinterpretar el objetivo o significado de los métodos que suceden durante el ciclo de vida de una aplicación tales como onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), mi problema es con el método onCreate().

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación tipo notepad, pero para poder mostrar un  código mas simplificado he hecho una aplicación muy simple en la que se ve el problema de igual manera.

Pasa que el método onCreate() se ejecuta cada vez que una actividad es llamada, es decir, no solo se ejecuta cuando la actividad es llamada por primera vez sino que también lo hace cada vez que esa actividad es accedida desde otra.

Cosas que destacar:

1---Este método no es llamado si doy al home del móvil y la tarea pasa a segundo plano lo cual según lo que he leído es perfectamente correcto.

2---Este método onCreate() de la primera actividad no es llamado si voy a la segunda y luego le doy al botón de atras el cual me manda  de vuelta a la primera actividad. De nuevo según lo leído tiene sentido y todo bien.

3---Mi gran problema, si construyo un intent en la actividad 2 que me mande a la actividad 1, en lugar de simplemente volver atrás con el boton de atrás del móvil (como he dicho en el punto dos) si que llama al método onCreate() de la actividad 1 de nuevo.

Entonces.. yo leí que el metodo onCreate() solo se ejecuta una vez a lo largo de la vida de la aplicación, por supuesto si fuerzo el cierre de la aplicación el método onCreate() si que sería llamado de nuevo  de acuerdo a lo que he leido y al dibujo del ciclo de vida.

Mi pregunta es ¿Por qué es el metodo onCreate() llamado entre actividades si creas intents para acceder entre ellas(tanto de la primera a la segunda, como de la segunda a la primera) si cuando cambias de actividad se ejecuta onStop() y la actividad no es visible después se ejecuta onstart() y no pasa  por onCreate()?

No me deja publicar mas de dos vínculos pero los toast que se ejecutan en el oncreate() lo hacen en el caso  3 mencionado, si cambio de actividad a traves de un intent se ejecutan tanto de la primera actividad a la segunda como de la segunda a la primera

[image: imagen que representa la actividad 1]

[image: Imagen que representa la actividad 2]

Comment: por favor, añade código en formato texto. Si lo haces en imágenes no podemos copiarlo para ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es volver a la actividad anterior sin que se ejecute el método `onCreate()` de nuevo lo que tienes que hacer es utilizar el método `finish()` para finalizar la segunda actividad en vez de realizar un `intent` a la primera. De esta manera se cerrara la segunda actividad y volverás a la primera actividad sin que esta vuelva a ejecutarse.

```
boton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
        }
    });
```

## Edición

Para recibir los datos de una actividad cuando esta se cierre debes lanzarla utilizando el método `startActivityForResult()` en vez de `startActivity()`. El método startActivityForResult() recibe dos parámetros, el primero es el intent y el segundo un código(ese código identificara los datos que se enviaran de la actividad cuando la cierren), el código debe de ser un numero de tipo int, puede ser 1.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Enlace.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

En la actividad que lanzas, en tu caso `Enlace` debes de obtener el intent que la lanzo, con el método `getIntent`. Con este intent retornaras los datos de regreso a la actividad principal. Para enviar los datos de regreso utilizas el método `putExtra()` del intent y pasas el intent como parámetro al método `setResult()`, este método recibe dos parámetros, el intent y un Código, que en este caso el código es una variable heredada de la clase padre de la actividad.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
i.putExtra("RESULTADO", "hola");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Por ultimo en la actividad desde la que lanzas la otra, en tu caso `MainActivity` debes sobrescribir el método `onActivityResult()` y obtienes los datos enviados desde la actividad cerrada.

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ir);

        Toast.makeText(this, "CREANDO EN LA 1:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Enlace.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            String texto = data.getStringExtra("resultado");
        }

    }

}
```

#### Lanzar

```
public class Lanzar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button boton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ir);

        Toast.makeText(this, "CREANDO EN LA 2:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        boton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.putExtra("saludo", "hola");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar, entiendo tu respuesta pero yo usaba los intents  en la segunda actividad para asi poder pasarle datos de vuelta a la primera actividad, sabes como se haria para pasar datos asi usando finish()

Comment: Si claro, para eso debes utilizar en tu MainActivity  `startActivityForResult` en vez de `startActivity` y sobrescribir el método `onActivityResult()` para recibir los datos de la actividad que cierres. Edito mi respuesta para explicarte mejor.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, ya te he entendido, siempre leía una solución con onActivityResult en el foro inglés pero en tu idioma origen se entiende muchisimo mejor, perdona por lo de las imágenes, otro usuario se ha quejado porque al ponerlo en formato imágenes no podías copiarlo y habras tenido que escribirlo todo a mano, es mi primera pregunta desde que me registre ayer en este foro disculpad. Te marco la respuesta como positiva